# XPATH encoded HTML in tag

Tags: parsing, xpath

`

```
<item>
<title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</title> 
   `    `      
<description>
&amp;#13;
&amp;#13;
&amp;#13;&lt;div class=&quot;videoInStoryC&quot;&gt;&amp;#13;
&lt;div id=&quot;emp-19102206-25558&quot; class=&quot;emp&quot;&gt;&amp;#13;
&lt;div class=&quot;warning&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;holding&quot; src=&quot;http://bac.com/asfg.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;ipsim dlor&quot; /&gt;&amp;#13;
&lt;/div&gt;&amp;#13;  &lt;/div&gt;&amp;#13;
&amp;#13;
&lt;p class=&quot;caption&quot;&gt;ipfi fks: &quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amel&quot;&lt;/p&gt;&amp;#13;
&lt;/div&gt;&amp;#13;
&amp;#13;
</description>  
</item>
```

`

I have a RSS feed coming with the encoded HTML in the  tag. I would like to extract the URL source in the IMG tag of the encoded HTML.
In this case the URl is http://bac.com/asfg.jpg .
I have used img/@src but no success, i assumed because of the encoded Html. 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
parse-xml(replace(/item/description, "&#13;", ""))//img/@src
```

if you had an XPath 3.0 interpreter (but you don't)

You could use something like

```
filter(/item/description, 'src="([^"]*)"', 1)
```

if your interpreter had something like a filter function to apply a regular expression to a string. (but it doesn't)

You can use

```
 replace(replace(/item/description, '.*src="', '', 's'), '".*', '', 's')
```

if you have an XPath 2.0 interpreter and only one image in the text